# how can i filter a python get request response to only show specific data

Tags: python, api, python-requests, opensea

I get stats from opensea.io, but om only interested in the floor price. I have tried adding payload to my requests.get but im still given the same response. below is my code and below that is my response

```
import requests
headers = {"accept": "application/json"}
slug = 'doodles-official'
baseurl = 'https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/'
addon = '/stats'
doodles = baseurl+slug+addon
payload = {'floor_price': ' '}
r = requests.get(doodles, headers=headers, params=payload)

print(r.text)
```

```
{"stats":{"one_hour_volume":6.99,"one_hour_change":0.0,"one_hour_sales":1.0,"one_hour_sales_change":0.0,"one_hour_average_price":6.99,"one_hour_difference":6.99,"six_hour_volume":20.834000000000003,"six_hour_change":0.0,"six_hour_sales":3.0,"six_hour_sales_change":0.0,"six_hour_average_price":6.944666666666667,"six_hour_difference":20.834000000000003,"one_day_volume":27.834000000000003,"one_day_change":-0.016834683828671863,"one_day_sales":4.0,"one_day_sales_change":0.0,"one_day_average_price":6.958500000000001,"one_day_difference":-0.4765999999999977,"seven_day_volume":309.110982,"seven_day_change":0.45300639422315325,"seven_day_sales":42.0,"seven_day_average_price":7.359785285714286,"seven_day_difference":96.37208199999998,"thirty_day_volume":1279.7464910000008,"thirty_day_change":-0.47290656802367925,"thirty_day_sales":156.0,"thirty_day_average_price":8.203503147435903,"thirty_day_difference":-1148.1845234344428,"total_volume":150854.48212122018,"total_sales":24131.0,"total_supply":10000.0,"count":10000.0,"num_owners":5401,"average_price":6.251480755924751,"num_reports":1,"market_cap":73597.85285714285,"floor_price":6.8}}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I added payload vaiable to get.request payload = {'floor_price': ' '}
r = requests.get(doodles, headers=headers, params=payload) and was expecting it to print only the 'Floor_price' but instead was given all the stats again

Comment: Not sure about their api, but if you just wanted to get that piece of info from the response you could do `print(json.loads(r.text)['stats']['floor_price'])`

Comment: This worked perfectly, the filter needed to be in the print statement

Answer (score 0):

Even though it looks you already got it working, there's still some room for improvement.

1. No need to include the headers - the requests library will automatically include them for you.
2. No need to import the `json` library either, you can just call the `json()` method on the response object itself, which [automatically detects](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/4ea09e49f7d518d365e7c6f7ff6ed9ca70d6ec2e/requests/models.py#L868-L892) which encoding to use.

**Suggested revisions:**

```py
import requests

base_url = "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/"
slug = "doodles-official"
endpoint = "/stats"
  
url = base_url + slug + endpoint 

params = {"floor_price": " "}

resp = requests.get(url, params=params)

data = resp.json()
floor_price = data["stats"]["floor_price"]
print(floor_price)
```